# How to kill/stop task/timer with manual given time

Tags: java

My code

```
     setSelectedTime(duration){
        duration = 5 //this duration can be dynamic. User can select the time in minutes 
        timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run(){
            try {
                performing task Here.... 
            } catch(Exception e) {
                log.error("Exception"+e);
            }
        }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, duration*60*1000);

}
```

How to kill the existing timer/task when user change the input.

Comment: Well [`Timer#cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()) and [`TimerTask#cancel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel()) seem like good candidates

Comment: Am getting timer as null @MadProgrammer in that condition

Comment: Keep a single instance of `Timer`, when you create your `TimerTask`, keep a reference to it as well, so when you need to, you can just `cancel` them